# python regex - replace newline (\n) to something else

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to convert multiple continuous newline characters **followed by a Capital Letter** to "____" so that I can parse them.

For example,

```
i = "Inc\n\nContact"
i = re.sub(r'([\n]+)([A-Z])+', r"____\2", i) 

In [25]: i
Out [25]: 'Inc____Contact'
```

This string works fine. I can parse them using ____ later.

However it doesn't work on this particular string.

```
i =  "(2 months)\n\nML"
i = re.sub(r'([\n]+)([A-Z])+', r"____\2", i)

Out [31]: '(2 months)____L'
```

It ate capital M. 
What am I missing here?

Comment: place the `+` inside the brackets - `([\n]+)([A-Z]+)` - or just leave it out

Comment: What is particular string? please update your post with

Comment: @Saleem i =  "(2 months)\n\nML"

Comment: @SebastianProske i = re.sub(r'([\n+])([A-Z])+', r"____\2", i) still eats first Capital letter.

Comment: @BYOR see my edit - you moved the wrong `+` :P

Comment: As @SebastianProske points out, you need to place the `+` inside the brackets, like so: `i = re.sub(r'(\n+)([A-Z]+)', r"____\2", i)` Additionally, no square brackets around only **one** character is needed.

Comment: @SebastianProske or remove it entirely from the second set

Comment: Well, it's simple regex. See https://regex101.com/r/oE9iV3/1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**EDIT** To replace multiple continuous newline characters `(\n)` to `____`, this should do:

```
>>> import re
>>> i =  "(2 months)\n\nML"
>>> re.sub(r'(\n+)(?=[A-Z])', r'____', i)
'(2 months)____ML'
```

`(?=[A-Z])` is to assert "newline characters followed by Capital Letter". [REGEX DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/yO8qT2/1).

Answer (score 1):

Well let's take a look at your regex `([\n]+)([A-Z])+` - the first part `([\n]+)` is fine, matching multiple occurences of a newline into one group (note - this wont match the carriage return `\r`). However the second part `([A-Z])+` leeds to your error it matches a single uppercase letter into a capturing group - multiple times, if there are multiple Uppercase letter, which will reset the group to the last matched uppercase letter, which is then used for the replace.

Try the following and see what happens

```
import re    
i = "Inc\n\nABRAXAS"
i = re.sub(r'([\n]+)([A-Z])+', r"____\2", i)
```

You could simply place the + inside the capturing group, so multiple uppercase letters are matched into it. You could also just leave it out, as it doesn't make a difference, how many of these uppercase letters follow.

```
import re    
i = "Inc\n\nABRAXAS"
i = re.sub(r'(\n+)([A-Z])', r"____\2", i)
```

If you want to replace any sequence of linebreaks, no matter what follows - drop the `([A-Z])` completely and try

```
import re
i = "Inc\n\nABRAXAS"
i = re.sub(r'(\n+)', r"____", i)
```

You could also use `([\r\n]+)` as pattern, if you want to consider carriage returns

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'[\r?\n]')
test_str = u"(2 months)\n\nML"
subst = u"_"

result = re.sub(p, subst, test_str)
```

It will reduce string to

```
(2 months)__ML
```

See [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oE9iV3/1)